# XAML designer can't load resource file at design time

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

We have two products which share a resource DLL project.  There are three different resource classes in the DLL.  One is for a shared backend, a second is for one product and the last one for the other product.

One of the products is a WPF windows application.  The application has a static class called `MyCommands`:

```
public static class CarSystemCommands {

    public static RoutedUICommand CameraStatus { get; set; }

    public static RoutedUICommand CancelChanges { get; set; }

    . . .

    static CarSystemCommands() {
        CameraStatus = new RoutedUICommand( Car.Dashboard_CameraStatus, "CameraStatus", typeof( CarSystemCommands ) );
        CancelChanges = new RoutedUICommand( Car.Common_CancelChanges, "CancelChanges", typeof( CarSystemCommands ) );
        . . .
    }
}
```

Everything compiles and run fine.

Now, I have a User Control, call it `CameraConfiguration`, in the project which uses the same resource file.  When I view that User Control in the XAML designer, it displays fine.

The `CameraConfigurtaion` User Control is included in another User Control, call it `SettingsEditor`.  When I view the `SettingsEditor` in the XAML designer, I get an error:

> Exception: Cannot create an instance of "CameraConfiguration".

Viewing the various stack traces, I get to one that reads:

> FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Resources, Version=5.1.15588.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

The resource project just has the default references.  It's not referencing any other DLL or project.

As I said, everything compiles & runs correctly.  And the control which is reporting the problem displays perfectly fine when I edit it in the designer.

Does anybody have any ideas as to what's causing this problem?  Or how I could fix it?  It's annoying not to be able to view the control as you make changes to it.

**EDIT**

Since I've posted this question, I've moved from VS2012 to VS2013, and then to VS2015.  This problem is still happening!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I had used Visual Studio 2010 and I had a couple of solutions. In one of the solution I had controls and data model shared between other project. Every time when I rebuilded (not builded) this project in other solution I had error during desing time (application runs perfectly). I had to  clear the second solution and build it once again. Now I have visual Studio 2012 and I don't have errors that type (and I don't have this type of solution).

Comment: I'm running VS 2012 and I have this problem.  It's annoying but I'm living with it.  Though it'd be nice if I didn't have to . . .